# Как считать из бд данные с разных компьютеров единожды

Tags: база-данных, concurrency

Есть бд и очень большая таблица. Необходимо прочитать каждую запись в таблице **только один раз** блоками на нескольких компьютерах одновременно для последующей длительной обработки. Первой мыслью было: ввести дополнительное поле StatusCode, которое бы показывало, что данная запись уже обработалась, но если один компьютер взял на обработку один блок данных, но пока еще не сохранил изменения, то другой компьютер в это время считывает тот же набор данных и обрабатывает его второй раз, что очень плохо.

Для наглядности, написал маленькую программу на C#, хотя, думаю, кто его не знает, в принципе поймет

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Chek());
    List<Task> tl = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        tl.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Fun, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("wait");
    Task.WaitAll(tl.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(Chek());
    Console.WriteLine("removedCount: " + Reset());
}
static void Fun()
{
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var emp = db.Employees.Where(i => i.StatusCode == 0).Take(10).ToList();
            foreach (var item in emp)
            {
                //выполняем что-то с каждым элементом, что должны выполнить ОДИН раз
                item.StatusCode++;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
            else
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }

}
static int Reset()
{
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        return db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Employees SET StatusCode=0 WHERE StatusCode>0");
    }
}
static int Chek()
{
    using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
    {
        return db.Employees.Where(i => i.StatusCode > 0).Count();
    }
}
```

И результат

[image: 60 из 200]

Ожидаемо должно быть 200 (20 потоков меняют блоки по 10)

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Начните с понимания, что запись/блок, который _один компьютер взял на обработку_, в Вашей схеме НИКАК не отличается от записи/блока, который на обработку никто не взял. Тут даже генетические алгоритмы спасуют, что уж о тупом коде говорить... так что без пометки "взято на обработку" - ну никуда.

Comment: Кол-во компьютеров фиксировано? Тогда если их допустим 3, то все записи рассчитываются на 1-2-3. Один берёт первые записи, второй второе, третий третьи.

Comment: @Sergey, не фиксировано

Comment: Тогда применяйте запросы `select for update`. Второй комп выполнив такой заброс для того же блока получит фигвам, потому что записи уже заблокированы в другой транзакции. тогда надо просто перейти к следующему блоку. И т.д. рано или поздно доберётся до свободного (не заблокированного) блока. Примерно так. Уточните тему блокировок и изоляции транзакций в гугле. Как минимум должна быть опция "не ждать освобождение блокировки". Например в postgres `select тоси-боси for update nowait`

Comment: А вообще надо делать по-современному. Один процесс читает записи (по-одной или болками) и отправляет мессагу в очередь сообщений (messaging service). Обработчики читают из очереди эти мессаги. Кто первый вытащил мессагу, тот и обрабатывает записи, с ней связанные. В мессагу можно сразу паковать или записи (чтобы не извлекать из базы второй раз) или их id-шники. Обработчики могут подключать/отключаться динамически в любом количестве. В виндовсе имеется встроенная служба сообщений. Программируется легко. Кстати сам на c# применял.

Comment: @Sergey, то есть на стороне бд такой маленький бэкенд? а можно подробнее про службу сообщений?

Comment: Если нужно действительно быстро, то можно и в принципе по другому. Штатными средствами базы (обычно это работает быстрее) выгружаете  нужные данные в файл, доступный всем компам-обработчикам. Далее каждый из них читает и обрабатывает свою часть (каждый знает общее количество и рассчитывает смещение). Локальные с файлом обработчики (на разных CPU) для ускорения могут использовать mmap.

Comment: @Sergey Судя по предлагаемому `select for update` Вы полагаете, что у автора MySQL. Не объясните, почему? даже если это и верно... Также Вы предлагаете очередь сообщений - т.е. полагаете, что у автора все клиенты работают в одном инстансе ОС. Опять же - почему? и опять же даже если это верно... Мне не удалось найти фактов за эти догадки - что я не вижу?

Comment: @Akina `select for update` не является "монополией" MySQL. Я даже считаю, что это стандарт sql. Хотя сам стандарт ни в одной редакции не видел (он платный и мне не по карману), но вот из документации к postgres https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html

Comment: @Akina За давностью лет может чего-то не помню про msmq, но обычно ничто не мешает подключаться к удалённому серверу очередей. Например к ActiveMQ из мира java. Уверен, что и для msmq что-то есть если не в коробке, то как дополнительный сервис. Во всяком случае припоминаю читал о маршрутизации и мостах между серверами очередей msmq.

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно вводить не поле для статуса "обработано", а поле для статуса "взято на обработку". Соответственно алгоритм: клиент пробует взять на обработку запись - т.е. тупо в поле статуса записи указать свой ID. Обычным UPDATE, с условием отбор а Status Is Null. Затем проверяет, успешна попытка или нет - обычным SELECT. Если попытка удачна - обрабатывай. Если же кто-то успел влезть и зарезервировать эту же запись себе (т.е. в поле Status оказался ID другого клиента) - ну не повезло, пробуем взять на обработку другую запись. Суммарно типа такого:

```
-- таблица 
CREATE TABLE data ( fieldset,
    Status DEFAULT NULL );

-- цикл резервирования записи на обработку
do
    UPDATE data SET Status = 'My ID' WHERE Status Is Null Limit 1;
    SELECT ID from DATA WHERE Status = 'My ID';
loop until recordset.recordscount=1

-- обработка зарезервированной записи
process recordset.fields("id")

-- пометка, что запись обработана
UPDATE data SET Status = 0 WHERE ID = recordset.fields("id")
```

Да, система не очень - не предусмотрено случая, когда запись взята, но не обработана (скажем, клиент отвалился). По-хорошему нужно ещё поле штампа времени, когда запись взята (и время. по истечении которого она считается свободной к резервированию).

Эдакая "ручная эмуляция транзакций" - если не хочется использовать штатные механизмы.

Comment: _если не хочется использовать штатные механизмы_ - почему же не хочется? просто я про них не знаю, видимо

Comment: Я имею в виду штатный механизм блокирования отобранной записи - т.е. способ гарантировать, что между отбором записи и пометкой её как взятой в обработку никто не влезет со стороны с той же операцией.

Comment: вот можно подробнее про этот штатный механизм?

Comment: Штатный механизм - это транзакция. Может быть неявной (т.е. выбор пакуется в один запрос - UPDATE ... WHERE Status IS NULL) или явной. В некоторых диалектах существуют дополнительные механизмы такого рода блокировки (например, SELECT .. FOR UPDATE в случае MySQL).

Comment: _UPDATE ... WHERE Status IS NULL_ - это есть в Вашем примере, значит ли это, что Вы используете штатный механизм?

Comment: Да. Я убеждён, что обновлена будет запись, которая на момент начала выполнения запроса имела в поле NULL. Но поскольку я не знаю, как будет резервировать запись другой клиент, я дополнительно проверяю, что при обновлении в БД записан именно мой ID. И одновременно получаю ID зарезервированной мной записи. Если все клиенты резервируют так же, ситуации, когда первый запрос обновил 1 запись, а второй вернул 0 записей, быть не должно.

Comment: Да, этот момент я понял, я про другое: в ответе Вы написали _Эдакая "ручная эмуляция транзакций" - если не хочется использовать штатные механизмы_, но Вы использовали в ответе те самые штатные механизмы (неявный UPDATE ... WHERE Status IS NULL)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50726/discussion-between-akina-and-qutrix).

Answer (score 1):

> Первой мыслью было ввести дополнительное поле StatusCode, которое бы показывало, что данная запись уже обработалась

Введите два значения

1. Запись обрабатывается
2. Запись обработалась

Как это сделать в конкурентной среде - нужно смотреть конкретную БД. Для MySQL это будет так

```
SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE ... FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE my_table SET status = process WHERE id = :id
```

Для произвольной БД можно придумать такой запрос

```
UPDATE my_table SET status = guid WHERE ...;
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status = guid;
```

При этом приложение должно корректно обрабатывать ошибку `Lock conflict`

Плюс к этому можно добавить работу по некоторым группам. Скажем, если есть некоторое инкрементное поле `id` (число, или дата), то каждый из n потоков может работать с группами

```
var int len = (max(id) - min(id)) / n;
min(id) + len * i..min(id) + len * (i + 1)
```

где `i` - номер потока

Comment: И в результате все будет работать медленнее, чем с одного компа

Comment: проблема ведь никуда не исчезла: в то время как я одним потоком прочитал и отправляю update запрос, другой поток может взять эти же самые id, обработать и послать тот же update.

Работа по группам - это если один комп, у меня несколько и каждый может обрабатывать произвольное число

Comment: @Qutrix не может. При создании потока ему сразу выдается какой-то интервал и он работает только с этим интервалом

Comment: @Qutrix Если интервал выдать невозможно, то тогда работать только по статусам

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, но я ведь выше написал почему со статусами тоже не получится(

Comment: @Qutrix перечитайте мой ответ. Вам нужно **два** статуса

Comment: Партиционирование - самая здравая идея

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, все равно не понимаю: вот один поток достал пачку из 10 записей, в это время второй поток сделал то же самое, и так как первый поток еще не изменил статус этой первой пачки, второй поток достанет те же самые 10 записей, что и первый. Затем первый пошлет запрос на update со статусом обработки, это сделает затем и второй.

Comment: @Qutrix Пояснил в ответе

Answer (score 1):

Очень условный пример. Всё надо уточнять, изучать (давненько не брал в руки шашки)

Диспетчер работает только на одном компьютере:

```
...
var queue = MessageQueue.Create("emps");
var emps = db.Employees.ToList();
foreach (var emp in emps) {
    queue.send(emp);
}
...
```

Обработчиков может быть сколь угодно много:

```
...
var queue = new MessageQueue("emps");
while (true) {
    Message message = queue.Receive();
    Employe emp = message.getObject();
    transaction.begin();
    db.attach(emp);
    // что-то делаем с emp
    db.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();
}
...
```

Тут обработка по одной записи. Но аналогично можно сделать и рассылку блоков по несколько (или даже по много) записей.

На компьютере (хотя бы одном) должна работать служба очереди сообщений. Программы работают с очередью и базой, но не друг с другом.

Материалы по очередям сообщений в интернете есть, но за давностью не припомню ничего качественного. Что первое под руку попалось https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/web/level9/9_1.php. Не знаю насколько это полное руководство, но если что, как уже говорил, материал в сети есть. Если заинтересовало ищите сами.

За msmq не скажу, но у подобных сервисов есть такая полезная функция.
Отправка и получение мессаги может быть оформлено в транзакцию. Если запись в бд не удалась, то можно отменить и транзакцию очереди сообщение. Мессага вернётся в очередь и таким образом можно будет повторить попытку обработки позже без каких-либо дополнительных телодвижений.